# Returning derived class as base generic class

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

I'm writing unity scripts on C#. I've got my base class:

```
BaseMonoBehavior<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : BasePresenter
```

Some scripts extend this class, f.e.:

```
MyMonoBehaviour : BaseMonoBehaviour<MyPresenter> 
// MyPresenter extends BasePresenter
```

Then I have a type class with method, which adds this scripts as components to GameObject according to it's value:

```
void addComponentTo(GameObject gameObject) {
    if (myType == TYPE_A) {
        var script = gameObject.AddComponent<MyMonoBehaviour>();
    }
}
```

It's okay, but what can I do, if I want to return created script as base class? I want but can't write something like this:

```
BaseMonoBehaviour addComponentTo(GameObject gameObject) {
    if (myType == TYPE_A) {
        var script = gameObject.AddComponent<MyMonoBehaviour>();
        return script;
    }
    return null;
}
```

So, my question is simple - how can I do this? I want to use some methods of base class in the method, which calls *addComponentTo*...

P.S. Afterwards I'd like to get *MyMonoBehaviour* as *BaseMonoBehaviour* from *GameObject*, if it's possible, but it's yet another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `BaseMonoBehaviour` is generic on a presenter class, you could make `AddComponentTo` generic as well:

```
BaseMonoBehaviour<TP> AddComponentTo(GameObject gameObject) where TP : BasePresenter {
    if (myType == TYPE_A) {
        var script gameObject.AddComponent<MyMonoBehaviour>();
        return script;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then the caller would be able to call it as follows:

```
var component = AddComponentTo<MyPresenter>(gObj);
```

This requires all generic instances returned by `AddComponentTo` to be generic on the same type that you can specify at invocation point.

**Note:** If `AddComponentTo` creates generic instances that are generic on the same presenter, you could even make it non-generic, like this:

```
BaseMonoBehaviour<MyPresenter> AddComponentTo(GameObject gameObject) {
    if (myType == TYPE_A) {
        var script gameObject.AddComponent<MyMonoBehaviour>();
        return script;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
var component = AddComponentTo(gObj);
```

Comment: But your solution requires me to know concrete implementation of BasePresenter when calling this function, but I wanted to abstract from this. All I wanted is to give to some method my gameobject and it's type.. As I've understood, there is no delicate solution for that?

Comment: @KamoSpertsian In order to get back an instance of a generic class you need to provide its generic type parameters. You could return non-generic `MonoBehaviour`, but `BaseMonoBehaviour` requires a type argument which could be either generic (first solution) or fixed (second solution).